# pandas Dataframe plot line : how to add directly label on lines?

Tags: python, pandas

I put the following code :

```
ratio_result_selected_country.loc['3/17/20':].plot.line(figsize=(17,7), grid = True)
```

and the result is :
[image]

is it possible to add label  directly like this :

[image]

```
ax  = ratio_result_selected_country.loc['3/17/20':].plot(figsize=(17,7), grid = True)
for line , name in zip (ax.lines ,ratio_result_selected_country.columns ):
    y = line.get_ydata()[-1]
    ax.annotate(name,xy=(1,y),xytext=(6,0),color=line.get_color(),
               xycoords = ax.get_yaxis_transform(),textcoords ="offset points",
                size = 14, va="center"
               )

plt.show()
```

Comment: Here you go, use ax.annotate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237522/how-to-annotate-end-of-lines-using-python-and-matplotlib

Comment: Thank you so much for the link  :

Comment: [How to annotate end of lines using python and matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237522/how-to-annotate-end-of-lines-using-python-and-matplotlib) seems to answer to question.  Please vote to close this question as a duplicate.